# Check if time in millis is tomorrow

Tags: java, android, datetime

I want to query SQLite table and get records where the time field (which is a String representing long time in millis) is in the range of tomorrow from querying time.

I also have a field which holds the record date time like this:

> dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss

How would you recommend implementing this?

Comment: Does tomorrow mean the next calendar day, or within 24 hours (or between 24-48 hours from now)? I assume calendar days, but the answer would depend on that.

Comment: Query "between tomorrow 00:00 and tomorrow 23:59"; now, how you query depends on the API you use

Comment: Why are you using strings for this at all? And what time zone do you think of "tomorrow" in?

Comment: I need the tomorrow not the 24 houres from... i want to get the local time zone for tommorow. I would be happy to hear suggestions on how to better save data on the table and manipulate it easily

Comment: Time handling is more tricky that it sounds. Why don't you use JodaTime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment you are open to modify the schema for better performance. So it is better to save time as long (unix timestamp) in database and having an index on that. Once that is done you can simply get tomorrows date at 00:00 in local time zone and convert it to unix timestamp and query based on that. Here is how you can get tomorrows timestamp at 00:00,

```
public static long getTimeStampAt0000(long timestamp) {
  Calendar givenDate = Calendar.getInstance();
  givenDate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
  givenDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  givenDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  givenDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  givenDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  return givenDate.getTimeInMillis();
}

public static long getTimeStampAt0000ForTomorrow() {
  long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long nowAt0000 = getTimeStampAt0000(now);
  if (now == nowAt0000) {
    // if being queried at 00:00, we are assuming we want same or else we can just remove
    // this condition
     return nowAt0000;
  } else {
     return nowAt0000 + 86400000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLite doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says that it stores as:

> INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Are you *certain* you have milliseconds since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) or seconds?

The bundled java.util.Date and Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time.* package in Java 8.

Note that both java.util.Date and Joda-Time DateTime use milliseconds since epoch, while the new java.time uses nanoseconds. Multiply by `1000L` as needed.

When talking about "today" and "tomorrow" with a date-time, you must specify a time zone. The beginning and ending of a day depends on [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

```
// Simulate input.
long millis = DateTime.now().getMillis();

// Use a proper time zone name rather than 3-letter codes.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ); // Formerly known as Calcutta, India.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( millis, timeZone );
DateTime aDayLater = dateTime.plusDays( 1 );

// "Tomorrow" is a span of time.
DateTime startOfToday = new DateTime( timeZone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
// Interval comparison is done in "half-open" approach where beginning is inclusive and ending is exclusive.
Interval tomorrow = new Interval( startOfToday.plusDays( 1 ), startOfToday.plusDays( 2 ) );
boolean isDateTimeOccurringTomorrow = tomorrow.contains( dateTime );
boolean isADayLaterOccurringTomorrow = tomorrow.contains( aDayLater );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "millis: " + millis );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "aDayLater: " + aDayLater );
System.out.println( "startOfToday: " + startOfToday );
System.out.println( "tomorrow: " + tomorrow );
System.out.println( "isDateTimeOccurringTomorrow: " + isDateTimeOccurringTomorrow );
System.out.println( "isADayLaterOccurringTomorrow: " + isADayLaterOccurringTomorrow );
```

When run…

```
millis: 1392883763016
dateTime: 2014-02-20T13:39:23.016+05:30
aDayLater: 2014-02-21T13:39:23.016+05:30
startOfToday: 2014-02-20T00:00:00.000+05:30
tomorrow: 2014-02-21T00:00:00.000+05:30/2014-02-22T00:00:00.000+05:30
isDateTimeOccurringTomorrow: false
isADayLaterOccurringTomorrow: true
```